# Find the Supremum of $B$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(z_n)$ be the sequence given by
$$z_n = (−1)^n + \frac{1}{n} \qquad n \in \{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$$

Let $A\subset R$ be a subset with the properties: $\inf A = −2$ and $\sup A = 1$.

Let $$B :=  \{ a \cdot z_n \mid a \in A, n \in\Bbb{N}_+\}$$

> Find $\sup B$.

Comment: Your thoughts, please??

Comment: Should be some catch

Comment: I thought that $z_n$  could be divided into two subsequences, $z_n_k$ and $z_n_l$ with $n_k$ the even indices and $n_l$ the odd indices. Then the $sup(z_n)$=1. The $sup(A)=1$, and I thought $sup(Az_n)=supA*sup(z_n)$ because both the suprema are positive. So $sup(B)=1*1=1$.

Comment: what about multiplying both negatives? it could be a higher value

Comment: On wikipedia it says that $inf(Az_n)=inf(A)*inf(z_n)$ only holds for positive values, so I figured that $infA*inf(z_n)=-2*-1=2$ wouldn't work.

Comment: So you are not dealing with only positive sequences, and why do you think $\sup$ would work? Take a simpler example $-2, 1, -2, 1, \ldots$ and $-1, 1, -1, 1, \ldots$. Multiply pointwise - what is the $\sup$?

Comment: Because $z_n_k$ is a strictly positive subsequence, and a positive subsequence of B can be found which has a supremum of 1.

Comment: What if negative subsequence could be found, which converges to $\inf_k z_k$?

Comment: That would be $z_n_l$ which is the subsequence of odd indices which converges to $-1$ the infimum of $z_n$. Would it then be possible to multiply the two infima of $z_n$ and $A$ to get to the supremum $2$ of $B$? Could you use $sup(-A)=-inf(A)$?

Comment: it is formally incorrect, but this is the main idea - you pick numbers close enough to $\inf$s and multiply - you get some numbers - they are candidates to be close to $\sup$.

Comment: is $*$ the same multiplication and $\Bbb N+$ the same $\Bbb N\cup \{ 0\}$?

Comment: Would it be correct two use the subsequence $z_n_l$ which has $inf(z_n_l)=-1$, and a subsequence of B, $b_n$, which has $inf(b_n)=-2$, and then $-inf(z_n_l)=sup(-z_n_l)=1$ and $-inf(b_n)=sup(-b_n)=2)$. Now both the suprema are consisting of positive values and can be multiplied to obtain 2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I did show effort and my own solutions so far, so why would this be flagged?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the problem statement? As written, the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $A$ don't matter. The only thing that matters is which value you choose for $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that$$\large z_{2n}=1+\frac{1}{2n}\\z_{2n-1}=-1+\frac{1}{2n-1}$$therefore$$\large\sup_{n}\{z_n\}=\max\{\sup_{2n}\{z_{2n}\},\sup_{2n-1}\{z_{2n-1}\}\}=\max\{z_2,-\frac{1}{2}\}=z_2=\frac{3}{2}\\\large\inf_{n}\{z_n\}=\min\{\inf_{2n}\{z_{2n}\},\inf_{2n-1}\{z_{2n-1}\}\}=\min\{1,-1\}=-1$$therefore we have that:$$\forall a\in A,n\to -1<z_n\le \frac{3}{2}\quad ,\quad -2\le a\le1\to {a.z_n<2\\a.z_n\le \frac{3}{2}}$$which leads us to $$\forall b\in B\quad,\quad b<2$$which implies that $l=2$ is an upper bound for $B$. To prove that is least such bound it suffices to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $b\in B$ such that $b>2-\epsilon$. Now take $b=az_n$ for some $n$ and $a\in A$. Since $\inf A=-2$ we can get arbitrarily close to it i.e. $a=-2+\epsilon_1$ when $\epsilon_1>0$ and arbitrary. Therefore:$$b=a.z_n=(-2+\epsilon_1)(-1+\frac{1}{2n-1})=2-\epsilon_1-\frac{2}{2n-1}+\frac{\epsilon_1}{2n-1}$$ By choosing $n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}+\frac{1}{2}$ and $\epsilon_1=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ we get:$$2-\epsilon_1-\frac{2}{2n-1}+\frac{\epsilon_1}{2n-1}>2-\epsilon_1-\frac{2}{2n-1}>2-\frac{\epsilon}{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}=2-{\epsilon}$$which is what we wanted to show. Then:$$\sup B=2$$